# Semantic UI, how to customize menu styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui for the first time in my React app, the exact package I'm using: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu

I'm rendering my header using  like so:

```
  <Menu
    className='header'
  >
    <Container>
```

with a scss import to style header like so:

```
.header {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      to left,
      rgba(100,97,240,1) 0%,
      rgba(255,203,0,1) 100%
    )
    left
    bottom
    #FFF
    no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 4px;
}
```

React is rendering the component like so:

```
<div class="ui header menu">
    <div class="ui container">
       ....
```

The problem is that the .header styles in the import SCSS file are being ignored. While I'm sure I could add `!important` in my css file that feels like the wrong thing to do with Semantic UI and I'd like to understand the right way.

With Semantic-UI-React, how to I make the  use the desired styles? Do I need to add some menu.variables or menu.overrides etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can customize css using className. You can use style prop for custom css.
You can use this guide for customizing default styles:
[React Semantic-UI customized](http://g14n.info/2016/11/react-semantic-customized/)

Additionally if you encountered any issue generating `semantic.min.css`
 file you can refer this issue:[gulp build is not building semantic.min.css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6067)